# Using a Normally Closed PCB mounted Solid State Relay

Tags: transistors, pcb, switches, pcb-design, solid-state-relay

**Summary:**
Continuing my search for a solution to my problem, I have landed on normally closed solid state relays (NC 1 FORM B SSR). Could you tell me if I'm doing this right?

**What I need:**
What I need, is a switch, that is closed when the power to my MCU is off, and that is open when the power to my MCU is on. I have a 12V PWM coming in and when power is on, I substitute it with my own 12V PWM. **(Basically a normally closed switch, which opens completely when power is on.)**

In the schematic below, I have tried to illustrate my situation.

**Why I need it:**
Since PNP Transistors (due to high Emitter-Base Voltage), P-MOSFETs (due to at times negative Source-Drain Voltage) and JFETs (due to maximally 12V available as control signal) don't work, I have landed on SSRs.

I have no experience with PCB mounted SSRs, so I need your help.
I found this relay which seems to suit my application: [G3VM-353G](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0cce/0900766b80cce6a2.pdf)
Do you think this will work as intended?

**Schematic 1: My "challenge"/problem**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPbvIg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Schematic 2: Will this work?**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0fEzg.png)</sup>

Thank you!

**Edit specifiying the signal:**
As per request: The PWM signal to be passed through or interrupted is a 1kHZ, normally 0-12V, 0-100% duty cycle signal. To pass through states, the amplitude is sometimes modulated, changing it to 0-9V, 0-6V or 0-3V. Current is minimal (except for measuring, no current is drawn from the signal).
Voltage drop tolerance is ±3%, duty cycle tolerance is ±0.1%.

Comment: Does R2 need to be 100kohm or can it be (say) 1kohm or lower?

Comment: R2 represents my external "load" (specifically it's another system entirely, measuring the PWM signal I output). I can't control its size.

Comment: But, can you load the output of the relay with 100 ohms as a permanent fixture in your design? If so then the 65pF that Spehro mentions becomes fairly insignificant.

Comment: The PWM signal going to the load also has a varying amplitude which is important, so I cannot add any load to it, since that would yield a voltage drop. I need to pass through the signal as "clean" as possible. The relay datasheet already states 15 Ohm ON resistance and the C[IO] is only 0.8pF. Current leakage is indicated as 1uA maximum. That would mean the effect shouldn't be as strong as in Spehro's example, right?

Comment: It's not 0.8pF, it's 68pF - use the OMRON site http://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pdf/en-g3vm_353g.pdf. I think it might be a good idea to divulge the exact nature of the signal because at the moment nothing is looking promising except a mechanical relay (as mentioned in your previous question). Without compromising any potential solution state what the signal is and what it shoul;d connect to. State permissible losses and degredations to the signal also.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit confused about all the different capacitance values. I have edited the question and added some specifics. I have also added more information to the first schematic.

Comment: Am I simulating this correctly? https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/965aa6/ssrcoutsimulation/

Comment: The "current leak" and 65pF go from input to output - forget about R-OFF it is trivial.

Comment: So the simulation is good enough? I found this one with only 10pF C[OFF], is it better? http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/205/CPC1117N-4777.pdf

Comment: No, the "current leak" and 65pF go from input to output. That SSR looks better BUT why can't you use a mechanical relay?

Comment: Do you know any good PCB mounted, preferrably SMD, mechanical relays? I have limited space, so the smaller the better. I could only find huge once for 1A+, when all I need is around 100mA max.

Comment: You won't find a normal relay below 1A. How about this, is it too big: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/18364.pdf

Comment: Reed relays might be smaller - here's one that fits a different envelope; http://uk.farnell.com/standexmeder/kt12-1a-40l-smd/dry-reed-relay-spst-no-12vdc-1a/dp/2453577?ost=reed+relay&categoryId=700000006256

Comment: I need a normally closed (SPST-NC), if I understand the types corectly. So maybe this one: http://uk.farnell.com/standexmeder/dip12-1b72-19l/dry-reed-relay-spst-nc-12vdc-0/dp/2453559   ? Or I could also use SPDT and leave one of the terminals open right? And then use this: http://uk.farnell.com/hamlin/he721c0500/reed-relay-spdt-5vdc-0-25a-tht/dp/2292927   ?
I'm a bit overwhelmed by this so thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Going back to SSRs I found this one: [AQV414A](http://www2.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Panasonic-Industrial-Devices/AQV414A/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsUriz2CNI3E7Pzxx3witaf3tA7J1kWS08=). It seems to have everything I want: Small, SMD, 5V, C[OFF] 10pF. I tried simulating the influence of the Output capacitance and it gave me a resulting spike duration of 0.02us on the output. That sounds like something I can live with. Do you agree?

Comment: I can't say whether it is livable with! I have great reservations about the capacitance figure. If you look at figure 12, it suggests that the capacitance rises greatly as the voltage across the "contact" drops below 5V. This is typical of a MOSFET (device used inside SSR) so don't be so easily convinced. You juts have to look at any mosfet spec in detail to know that open-circuit output capacitance is going to be a headache.

Comment: I don't like headaches. :-) What did you think about the two reed relays I posted (DIP12-1B72-19L and HE721C0500)?

Comment: @Andyaka I went with the AQV414A SSR and I'm going to perform some tests once the PCB arrives on Monday to see how bad it is. Anyway I want to thank you for your help. If you want to summarize your comments here as an answer, I'll mark this question as answered.

Comment: Just report your findings and send a comment to me for a look. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It will sort-of work. The capacitance between terminals when the relay is off is typically about 65pF, so you'd see something like the green trace below (5kHz 50% square wave input shown) across the 100K resistor. Red trace is the 'PWM' input.

[image]

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, you're saying that even when the relay is off, some of the signal can still have an influence across its terminals? Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve what I want?

Comment: @Johis Not really since I have no idea what you actually want or whether the 100K resistor is realistic or not. Sometimes series-parallel switch combinations are used, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: I have a more detailed description of my case here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/172835/pnp-transistor-leak/ I have an external 12V PWM signal going through my board. When the power to my MCU comes on, I want to interrupt this signal and replace it with my own.
Edit: The Datasheet for this SSR states C[IO] to be 0.8pF.

Comment: Am I simulating this correctly? https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/965aa6/ssrcoutsimulation/